# Creating Google Doc from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am creating an approval application using Google Spreadsheets and Mail app. At the end of the process, I think it would be a nice touch to end with a Google Doc, instead of just a Google Spreadsheet that is not appealing to the recipients. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You could use the [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) to extract the information using getRange() to then create a Google Doc from the [Document Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/). If you have a template Google Doc that you want to use, you could the  [File Make Copy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#makeCopy(String)) (then using Document's replace text) to insert the necessary information.

Cheers.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do a mail merge. Check it the Autocrat script in the script gallery.